# Take user input and make a new file in multiple lines

Tags: ansible, ansible-awx

I want to take a user input from vars_prompt like:-

```
Enter names:- apple orange
```

and make a new file on a server with this output:-

```
apple
orange
```

how can i achieve this using lineinfile or blockinfile modules?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The playbook below with the input `Enter names:- apple orange`

```
- hosts: localhost
  vars_prompt:
    - name: fruits
      prompt: "Enter names"
      private: no
  tasks:
    - file:
        path: /tmp/fruits
        state: absent
    - lineinfile:
        path: /tmp/fruits
        create: yes
        line: "{{ item }}"
      loop: "{{ fruits.split(' ') }}"
```

gives

```
$ cat /tmp/fruits 
apple
orange
```